# inductance for choke inductor EMI filter

Tags: emc, common-mode-choke

How do you select the choke inductance for an EMI filter?
I'm trying to design an EMI filter for a primary side of a transformed which takes 230VAC and steps it down to 24VAC at maximum of 600VA (~3A input and 25A out)

Comment: What EMI noise are you trying to reduce? What part of the spectrum are you having problems with?

Comment: the secondary side of the transformer will be the input of a boost PFC which will then be followed by a buck converter. The EMI is just as a precaution as there will be switching elements at around 100-200kHz in these stages which could be fed back to mains

Comment: Designing filters is all about numbers. If you can't specify what you want or need then it's guesswork what values the filter will have.

Comment: An iron-core transformer into a PFC stage? Why?

Comment: For isolation purposes